# Behavior of JS unary plus operator applied on a string representing a negative hex

Tags: javascript, numbers, hex

[according to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators), when using the unary plus operator:

> Integers in both decimal and hexadecimal ("0x"-prefixed) formats are
>   supported. Negative numbers are supported (**though not for hex**). If it
>   cannot parse a particular value, it will evaluate to NaN.

But when I run this Jasmine test (the `toBe()` matcher applies a `===` operator):

```
   it("should return NaN when trying to convert a string representing a NEGATIVE HEX to the corresponding number", function() {
    var a = '-0xFF';        
    expect(typeof +a).toBe('number');
    expect(isNaN(+a)).toBeTruthy(); //Fails on Chrome and Opera...
  });
```

**It fails on Chrome and Opera** (and passes in IE, Safari and Firefox).

Is it a flaw in Chrome and Opera's engines or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may - or may not be seen as a flaw, depending on how one's attached to specifications. )

I've found an [interesting discussion](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=24156) regarding this behavior. Looks like Firefox was for once in the 'better-than-spec' camp, but then fixed it according to spec.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [EcmaScript specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf), the unary `+` operator applies the [[String-]to-Number-conversion](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf#p44) on the value (here a string), which accepts hex numbers - but not negative hex numbers.